# Read or edit document (ms-word and pdf ) which are exist in attachment

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have 2 files(ms-word and pdf) in attachement which receive from the client side. Is it possible to read and edit that document in Apex and Visualforce?
Please help me out.

Comment: You can search through pdfs and word documents if you attach them as files. You can't really read them as such. You can't edit word documents or pdfs in apex or visualforce unless you are willing to invest a serious amount of time and energy. I would not advice it. The easy solution would be to use a third party service for this.

Comment: Thank you @Kasper :) for your suggestion. Could you please suggest any third party tool which is available in app exchange.

Comment: I"m sorry @GmDeepakChonan21. I can't help you with that; I have never actually tried to do so.